# SharedPreferences: Can you access variables stored in sharedPreferences before onCreate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a child to the root of my firebase, I however want the new root to have the user's name. I am storing user information in a sharedpreference, Can I access this sharedPreference before onCreate

public static final String USER_PREFS = "END_PREFS";

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

final SharedPreferences user_data = getSharedPreferences("PESASEND_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child("Support").child((getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("END_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).getString("namekey", null));


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_us);
```

Comment: You can show your Ui after loading and have some progress bar before or you can use fragments

Comment: It will be a lot easier to help if you show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you have an Application context, you can access SharedPreferences.

You don't need to call onCreate() first.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I have taught myself how to do android apps and now starting with firebase, so am not sure exactly what application Context means.

Comment: Then jumping to Firebase might be putting the cart before the horse.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: I had actulally first used MySQL db, once I got that down, I am now working with firebase. This kind of what I am thinking.  private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child("Support").child((getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ADFT_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)).getString("namekey", null));